# Error : Incorrect syntax near order while using partition in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My query is to calculate cumulative total for every 6 weekcount..

```
;WITH CTE_Group AS (
   SELECT id, ClientId, extraId, weekCount,  Total1,Total2,       
         (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY extraId ORDER BY ClientId,weekCount) + 5) / 6 AS grp
   FROM Sale
)
SELECT id, id, ClientId, extraId, weekCount,  Total1,Total2, 
      SUM(Total1+Total2) OVER (PARTITION BY extraId, grp ORDER BY ClientId,weekCount)
FROM CTE_Group
```

But it shows "Incorrect syntax near order".

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I was able to parse your query,so there shouldn't be syntax error

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: Yes this works fine with version 2014. But showing error in sql 2012

Comment: Sql server 2012 should have no problem supporting this syntax. check compatability level, perhaps it's set to a lower version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ Gameiswar and Zohar. I will check out for compatibility.